# How to change the outline color of OutlinedTextField from jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-theme, android-textinputlayout, android-compose-textfield

Here is how OutlinedTextField code looks like in jetpack-compose:

```
OutlinedTextField(
    value = "",
    onValueChange = {},
    label = {Text("Input")}
)
```

The default color of the outline of this TextField is purple. I want to change the outline color along with the label obviously.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The default values used by the `OutlinedTextField` are defined in the **`TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors`** by the `focusedBorderColor`, `unfocusedBorderColor`, `disabledBorderColor`.

With **M2**:

```
focusedBorderColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.high),
unfocusedBorderColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled),
```

You can change the **`colors.primary`** and the  **`colors.onSurface`** in your theme.

With **M3**:

```
    focusedBorderColor: Color = OutlinedTextFieldTokens.FocusOutlineColor.toColor(),
    unfocusedBorderColor: Color = OutlinedTextFieldTokens.OutlineColor.toColor(),
```

In this case you can change the **`primary`** and the  **`outline`** colors in your theme.

Otherwise you can **override** them using something like:

```
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = "",
        onValueChange = {},
        label = {Text("Input")},
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
            focusedBorderColor = Green,
            unfocusedBorderColor = Yellow)
    )
```

[image]

Comment: We can use focusedLabelColor and unfocusedLabelColor to change the color of the label. Btw, thanks for showing me the path for more customization possibilities.

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti It is not working when "enable = false". Is there any workaround on that ? Thanks

Comment: @ArpitPatel If it has `enabled=false` you have to use the `disabledBorderColor` attribute

Comment: I only want to change outline color when user press on that not always. I was opening drop down on outlineTextField click and highlight that field so user will notify current state of screen.

Comment: With M3 you need to use `OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors()`.

Answer (score 12):

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun TelephoneEditText() {
    val textValue = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    OutlinedTextField(
        label = {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(
                    id = R.string.phoneNumber
                ),
                style = TextStyle(
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant,
                )
            )
        },
        placeholder = {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.phone_placeholder),
                style = TextStyle(
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
            )
        },
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
            focusedBorderColor = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
            unfocusedBorderColor = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
            focusedLabelColor = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
            cursorColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant
        ),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
        value = textValue.value,
        onValueChange = { textValue.value = it },
    )
    WhatsAppButton(textValue)
}
```

Colors.kt

```
val Yellow500 = Color(0XFFFFDE03)
val Blue700 = Color(0xFF0036FF)
val Pink500 = Color(0xFFf50057)
val Pink700 = Color(0xFFff5983)

val LightColors = lightColors(
    primary = Yellow500,
    primaryVariant = Blue700,
    secondary = Pink500,
    secondaryVariant = Pink700
)

val DarkColors = darkColors(
    primary = Yellow500,
    primaryVariant = Blue700,
    secondary = Pink700
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

for 1.0.0 beta-1

```
OutlinedTextField(
    value = "",
    onValueChange = {},
    label = {Text("Input")},
    color = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
            focusedBorderColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary.copy(alpha = 
              ContentAlpha.high),
            unfocusedBorderColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = 
              ContentAlpha.disabled),
            disabledBorderColor: Color = unfocusedBorderColor.copy(alpha =
              ContentAlpha.disabled),
            errorBorderColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.error,
    )
)
```

Set border colors depends on the situation using above parameter.

Answer (score 3):

With compose androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.04.01
Now you need to use colors.
For background use container color and for border use indicator color

```
  OutlinedTextField(
            searchValue.value,
            {
                searchValue.value = it
            },
            placeholder = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.hint_search_food)) },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text, imeAction = ImeAction.Search
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp),
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
                unfocusedContainerColor = fieldBackGroundColor,
                focusedContainerColor = fieldBackGroundColor,
                focusedIndicatorColor = fieldBackGroundColor,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = fieldBackGroundColor
            ),
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(Icons.Outlined.Search, "Search")
            },
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this property to change the border colors

```
OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
                    focusedBorderColor = // someColor,
                    unfocusedBorderColor = //someColor,
                )
```

Example,

```
OutlinedTextField(
                value = status,
                onValueChange = { status = it },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
                colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
                    focusedBorderColor = Grey80,
                    unfocusedBorderColor = Grey80,
                )

            )
```

You get a bunch of options to try on.

Comment: This is currently the way to go with M3.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is solution for M3:

```
colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                cursorColor = androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.medium),
                focusedIndicatorColor = androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.medium),
                focusedLabelColor = androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.medium)
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

In Compose 1.4.0 and Material 3, you can use the following:

```
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = "Hello",
        onValueChange = {},
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
            containerColor =,
            focusedBorderColor =,
            unfocusedBorderColor =
        ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to customize the outline color of a OutlinedTextField in Jetpack Compose (1.6.0), you can achieve this by using the colors parameter and specifically setting the focusedIndicatorColor and unfocusedIndicatorColor. In your case, you want the outline to be green when focused and red when unfocused.

Here's an example:

```
OutlinedTextField(
    value = value,
    onValueChange = onValueChange,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(vertical = 4.dp),
    placeholder = {
        Text(
            text = "Enter description",
            style = TextStyle(
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
        )
    },
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp),
    colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
        focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Green,
        unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Red
    )
)
```